# How to initialize tf.metrics members in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, metrics

The below is a part of my project code.

```
with tf.name_scope("test_accuracy"):
    test_mean_abs_err, test_mean_abs_err_op = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict)
    test_accuracy, test_accuracy_op         = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict)
    test_precision, test_precision_op       = tf.metrics.precision(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict)
    test_recall, test_recall_op             = tf.metrics.recall(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict)
    test_f1_measure = 2 * test_precision * test_recall / (test_precision + test_recall)
tf.summary.scalar('test_mean_abs_err', test_mean_abs_err)
tf.summary.scalar('test_accuracy', test_accuracy)
tf.summary.scalar('test_precision', test_precision)
tf.summary.scalar('test_recall', test_recall)
tf.summary.scalar('test_f1_measure', test_f1_measure)
# validation metric init op
validation_metrics_init_op = tf.variables_initializer(\
        var_list=[test_mean_abs_err_op, test_accuracy_op, test_precision_op, test_recall_op], \
        name='validation_metrics_init')
```

However, when I run it, errors occur like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run_dnn.py", line 285, in <module>
    train(wnd_conf)
  File "./run_dnn.py", line 89, in train
    name='validation_metrics_init')
  File "/export/local/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 1176, in 
variables_initializer
return control_flow_ops.group(*[v.initializer for v in var_list], name=name)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'
```

I realize that I cannot create a validation initializer like that. I want to re-calculate the corresponding metrics when I save a new checkpoint model and apply a new round of validation. So, I have to re-initialize the metrics to be zero.

But how to reset all these metrics to be zero? Many thanks to your help!

Answer (score 3):

I sovled the problem in the following way after referring to the blog ([Avoiding headaches with tf.metrics](https://steemit.com/machine-learning/@ronny.rest/avoiding-headaches-with-tf-metrics)).

```
# validation metrics
validation_metrics_var_scope = "validation_metrics"
test_mean_abs_err, test_mean_abs_err_op = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict, name=validation_metrics_var_scope)
test_accuracy, test_accuracy_op         = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict, name=validation_metrics_var_scope)
test_precision, test_precision_op       = tf.metrics.precision(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict, name=validation_metrics_var_scope)
test_recall, test_recall_op             = tf.metrics.recall(labels=label_pl, predictions=test_eval_predict, name=validation_metrics_var_scope)
test_f1_measure = 2 * test_precision * test_recall / (test_precision + test_recall)
tf.summary.scalar('test_mean_abs_err', test_mean_abs_err)
tf.summary.scalar('test_accuracy', test_accuracy)
tf.summary.scalar('test_precision', test_precision)
tf.summary.scalar('test_recall', test_recall)
tf.summary.scalar('test_f1_measure', test_f1_measure)
# validation metric init op
validation_metrics_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, scope=validation_metrics_var_scope)
validation_metrics_init_op = tf.variables_initializer(var_list=validation_metrics_vars, name='validation_metrics_init')
```

Answer (score 0):

a minimal working example that can be run line by line in a python terminal:

```
import tensorflow as tf
s = tf.Session()
acc = tf.metrics.accuracy([0,1,0], [0.1, 0.9, 0.8])
ini = tf.variables_initializer(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES))
s.run([ini])
s.run([acc])
```